# concatenate a rotation and a translation of cv::Mat to a eigen

Tags: opencv, transformation, eigen3

I am doing a 6-dof transformation with the RANSAC given in OpenCV and I now want to convert two matrices of cv::Mat to an Isometry3d of Eigen but I didn't find good examples about this problem.

e.g.

```
cv::Mat rot;
cv::Mat trsl;
// the rot is 3-by-3 and trsl is 3-by-1 vector.

Eigen::Isometry3d trsf;

trsf.rotation = rot; 
trsf.translation = trsl;  // I know trsf has two members but it seems not the correct way to do a concatenation.
```

Anyone give me a hand? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not a specialist of Eigen but have you tried creating a 4*4 opencv matrix that represents your transform in homogeneous coordinates and feeding the data to your isometry3d using the data() pointer? (a transpose function should intervene at one point to convert opencv row major matrix to an Eigen column major transform)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, you need an `Eigen::Map` to read the opencv data and store it to parts of your `trsf`:

```
typedef Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3, Eigen::RowMajor> RMatrix3d;

Eigen::Isometry3d trsf;
trsf.linear() = RMatrix3d::Map(reinterpret_cast<const double*>(rot.data));
trsf.translation() = Eigen::Vector3d::Map(reinterpret_cast<const double*>(trsl.data));
```

You need to be sure that `rot` and `trsl` indeed hold `double` data (perhaps consider using `cv::Mat_<double>` instead).

Comment: Please include header files.